# Function that returns a function that returns a function

Tags: python

I've been given this function. It returns the function `pair` that it also returns the function `f` I think. That is the part that tricks me, I don't know what `f(a, b)` is and how to use it.

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair
```

Comment: It is any function that takes two parameters and returns a value.

Comment: look into decorators

Comment: Try actually using it: `c = cons(2, 3)` gives you a function that takes a function. So pass it some functions: `c(lambda x, y: x+y)`, `c(print)`, etc. and see what they give you.

Comment: `cons` is a weird name for this function—I'd expect a function with that name to return a pair of values bound together in a tuple, or an instance of a `Node` class, etc, not to return a function _named_ `pair` that accessed those values. Unless this is part of someone's larger sample for how to do lazy lists via trigger functions, or something like that. It would be very helpful for you to tell us where you got this code, so if it _is_ part of something like that, we can explain it in context instead of abstractly.

Comment: Is part of an interview question: ´cons(a, b)´ constructs a pair, and ´car(pair)´ and ´cdr(pair)´ returns the first and last element of that pair. For example, ´car(cons(3, 4))´ returns 3, and ´cdr(cons(3, 4))´ returns 4. I was asked to implement car an cdr

Comment: Since `cons` returns a _function_ object, is seems that `car` and `cdr` should fail. If the code you provided is correct, I'm really not sure what  something like `car(cons(3, 4))` is even suppose to mean. You can't get the 'first' element of a function (unless, of course in this case, you dig the variables from the closure returned by `cons`, but let's hope that's not what's going on).

Comment: @ChristianDean I'm with you, this seems like a terrible question for an interview unless the job is reverse engineering code? `def car(p): return p.func_closure[0].cell_contents` is just trivia. To actually use it in code would be an awful idea.

Comment: I was able to solve it with all your helpuf answers but not in the way the questions requests. As ChristianDean and TemporalWolf said, it is a weird question for an interview. By the way, I got it by mail for practice, not for an actual interview.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that interview question. The nested function returns is worth knowing (your question), how to extract variables is not.

Comment: Yup, I agree with @TemporalWolf OP. Don't worry about questions like this much. If the question is asking you do actually accesses values from closure cells, then I'd just ignore it. Actually, if questions like this come up often in your work interview, it may be a good idea to have a talk with the interviewer.

Comment: That's true, from what I read the company uses functional programming languages, so this question may be focused on lambda functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets analyse this from inside out:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair
```

**The innermost level** is `return f(a, b)` - that obviously calls function `f` with arguments `(a, b)` and returns whatever the result of that is.

**The next level** is `pair`:

```
def pair(f):
    return f(a, b)
```

Function `pair` takes a function as an argument, calls that function with two arguments `(a, b)` and returns the result. For example:

```
def plus(x, y):
    return x + y

a = 7
b = 8
pair(plus)  # returns 15
```

**The outermost level** is `cons` - it constructs function pair which has arbitrary `a` and `b` and returns that version of pair. E.g.

```
pair_2_3 = cons(2,3)

pair_2_3(plus)  # returns 5, because it calls plus(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

To help you understand what is going on, consider the following example:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

def my_func(a, b):
    return a + b

# cons returns a function that takes a function arg and calls it with args (a, b),
# in this case (1, 3). Here a, b are considered "closured" variables.
apply_func = cons(1, 3)

print apply_func(my_func) # prints 4
```

Answer (score 1):

> . . . I don't know what `f(a, b)` is and how to use it.

`f(a, b)` is simply a function call. All the code you provided does is define a function that returns a function. The function returned from the first function, *itself* returns a function. I assume the way it would be used is perhaps something like:

```
>>> cons(1, 2)(lambda x, y: x + y)
3
>>>
```

The above code would be equivalent to:

```
>>> pair_func = cons(1, 2) # return the `pair` function defined in `cons`
>>> f = lambda x, y: x + y 
>>> pair_func(f) # apply the `f` function to the arguments passed into `cons`.
3
>>>
```

It might also help to note that the `pair` function defined in this case, is what's know as a *closure*. Essentially, a closure is a function which has access to local variables from an enclosing function's scope, *after* the function has finished execution. In your specific case, `cons` is the enclosing function, `pair` is the closure, and `a` and `b` are the variables the closure is accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you could share the complete question then we might be able to help you better. Meanwhile what I can tell you here is that in the return of pair(f) the program is calling a function f which takes two arguments a and b. This function f(a,b) is called and then its value will be returned to pair(f).

But the point to note here is that in pair function we already have a local variable f, so when we will try to call the function f(a,b) it will give us UnboundedLocalVariable error. Therefore, we will need to change the name of this function from f to something else.

Comment: My bad, the question is in the 5th comment.